# Textarea extra row in FireFox browser

Tags: html, firefox, textarea

In FireFox HTML `<textarea>`s have one more row than specified in the property `rows`. If you are on FireFox you can see here:

```html
<textarea rows="2">
This clearly has 3 rows and not 2 like you might think.
</textarea>
```

If you are not using FireFox right now then this is what the snippet result looks like to me:

[image]

Comment: i don't see  any issue in your snippet

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal Please post an image showing what you see.

Comment: see https://imagebin.ca/v/3dm6sbn4JLPV

Comment: It works fine on Chrome, but I am seeing the issue in FF 56.0 on Windows. (Also, if you change rows to 1, it shows 2 rows), so it might be a bug in FF? You can override the height using CSS, if thats any help, e.g. `textarea{ height:30px;}`

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes it seems to be a problem with FF.

Comment: Yes I only checked on chrome might be some issue with FF

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's an age-old bug in Firefox that still hasn't been fixed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33654.

There is a workaround:

```
textarea {
  overflow-x: hidden
}
```

I don't know if this workaround could cause any issue - is it ever possible for a `textarea` to overflow horizontally?

Comment: Mozilla still haven't fixed it.  The bug's had two coming-of-age parties since I posted this answer (depending on your view of coming-of-age - it's 22 this year).

From the lack of comments, I assume there are no side-effects with this workaround.  Maybe the bug is something we'll just have to learn to live with.

Comment: I wonder if you fiddled with the word-wrap settings for `textarea` you could create a case where this workaround affects the result.  But it would be an academic exercise; surely no-one in their right mind would do that on a public-facing site (though Google and Facebook seem to be doing their damdest to make their sites and software as unusable as possible, so the jury's still out).

Answer (score 0):

for a correct evaluation of rows  attribute of tag textarea
  you should remember that this is thinked for work on combination with cols

and for cols (  form MDN  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea
) you have
    `cols`
The visible width of the text control, in average character widths. 
If it is specified, it must be a positive integer. If it is not specified, the default value is 20 (HTML5).

so the number of the rows  is based  not only on the value you specify for rows but also on the lenght of the text calculated 
 in  average character widths on the cols lenght value

Answer (score -1):

my advice will be for you not to use cols and rows attributes. Use CSS width and height properties to ensure a consistent experience across browsers.